# How to convert a buffer in an array in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

How to convert a buffer in an array?

Buffer (Hex values):

```
myBuffer = <Buffer 48 65 6c 6c 6F >
```

I want a a variable type array like this:

```
myArray = [48, 65, 6c, 6c, 6F] // Hex values
  or  
myArray = [72, 101, 108, 108, 111] // Decimal values
```

**IMPORTANT**: I don't want to use a `for` loop to traverse byte to byte of the buffer. I want to know if there is a native way to convert Buffer to Array.

Comment: `<Buffer 48 65 6c 6c 6F >` is string or tag.And what is the relation ship between `[48, 65, 6c, 6c, 6F] 
  or like this 
[72, 101, 108, 108, 111]` these arrays ? .In html `<Buffer 48 65 6c 6c 6F >` is invalid one

Comment: @prasanth the first array appears to be in hexadecimal and the second array is the hexadecimal values in decimal it seems. I think they are referring to Buffer objects in Node, not strings/tags.

Comment: @prasanth OP is talking about ArrayBuffer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer

Comment: @GerardoFurtado but `<Buffer 48 65 6c 6c 6F >`  is not look like Arraybuffer dom.its like tag or something else of string

Comment: @prasanth That's probably because OP doesn't know how to write it, or maybe I'm indeed wrong and this is a completely different thing... anyway, the best course of action here is voting to close as *"unclear what you're asking"*.

Comment: Unclear!?!? There is a buffer exactly as indicated with each one of those numbers and I want to convert to a variable of type ARRAY. What is not clear?!?

Comment: @wBB As `Buffer` is not an actual thing in native JavaScript. You could be either referring to `ArrayBuffer` or Node.js `Buffer`. Though the format `<Buffer 48 65 6c 6c 6f>` looks like Node.js `Buffer` in console.log to me so I guess you are referring to Node.js `Buffer`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I changed the topic title. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are referring to Node.js Buffer. If this is the case, you can simply do this:

```
var buf = new Buffer([72,101,108,108,111]) //<Buffer 48 65 6c 6c 6f>
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(buf) //[72,101,108,108,111]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about arraybuffer, try this method:

```
function ab2str(buf) {
return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
}
```

If you're talking about nodejs buffer object, try this:

```
let bufferOne = Buffer.from('This is a buffer example.');
console.log(bufferOne);

// Output: <Buffer 54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 61 20 62 75 66 66 65 72 20 65 78 61 6d 70 6c 65 2e>

let json = JSON.stringify(bufferOne);
console.log(json);

// Output: {"type":"Buffer","data":   [84,104,105,115,32,105,115,32,97,32,98,117,102,102,101,114,32,101,120,97,109,112,108,101,46]}
json = JSON.parse(json);
json.data.forEach(e=> console.log(e.toString(16))); 
// Output: 54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 61 20 62 75 66 66 65 72 20 65 78 61 6d 70 6c 65 2e
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES6, this would also work:

```js
const buffer = new Buffer([72,101,108,108,111])
const arr = [...buffer] //[72,101,108,108,111]
```